# Yii2: Attach behavior to every controller

Tags: yii2

How do we attach a behavior to all web controllers in the application?

I understand this is *theoretically* possible with dependency injection, so I assumed something like this would work:

```php
Yii::$container->set('yii\web\Controller', [
    'as myBehavior' => [
        'class'     => 'app\behaviors\MyBehavior',
    ],
]);
```

however DI requires an exact class match (attaching to a parent class will not work). There is no way to know all the controller names in advance, especially when most are coming from 3rd party modules.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

EDIT: The purpose of this is to dynamically add controller filters (which are just a special type of behaviors). Therefore attaching the behavior during the [`EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION-detail) event is not sufficient, because it is triggered long after request filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module's (and application's) `beforeAction` event is triggered before the controller's version of that event. You can take advantage of that and use it to attach behaviors to current controller.

For example in your web.php config:

```php
return [
    'on beforeAction' => function() {
        Yii::$app->controller->attachBehavior(
            'myBehavior',
            \app\behaviors\MyBehavior::class
        );
    },
    // ... other configurations
];
```

Of course the disadvantage is that the behavior is not attached from the start.

**NOTE**: If your goal is attaching a filter to each controller, you can simply attach it to application itself instead of controllers.

Comment: Woah you are right. Simply attaching filters to the application is possible! It even says so in the docs ( https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-filters ). For future reference: "Besides controllers, you can also declare filters in a module or application. When you do so, the filters will be applied to all controller actions belonging to that module or application"

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, I must say. I could not find the simple solution for this but I have this hacky idea. You could take advantage of Yii autoloader and load your version of `yii\web\Controller` instead of the original one.

To do that:

1. Copy the original file from vendor and place it in your app
2. Don't change the original namespace and name.
3. Add your behavior config (or just the behavior's code, whatever) inside.
4. Add this line below in a place that will be called every time the app runs (like entry point file or bootstrap file, it must be called **after** `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php` file is `required`):

   ```
   Yii::$classMap['yii\web\Controller'] = ''; // replace '' with the path to your version
                                              // of yii\web\Controller
   ```

Now, every time autoloader tries to load `yii\web\Controller` it will load your version instead so it should work like you want it.

The obvious con of this is that you will have to check manually if the original file has not been updated when upgrading Yii to make it up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

Child controller behavior depends on AccesControler behavior

```
   class WorkerimgController extends OfficeController{
    public function behaviors()
    {
      return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
      ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What a terrible idea. So now I have to manually modify all 1000 controllers in my app, including the ones from 3rd party vendors...

Comment: Thank You! You are right about this disadvantage in this case. EVERYBODY please read about that before using this variant.